# returning checkBox checked null

Tags: php

I'm having a problem getting the values of selected checkbox in my php file

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="obj">Objetivos PAE <a href="#" id="trigger">(Ver aqui)</a></label><br>
    <div id="pop-up">
        <h3>Objetivos PAE</h3>
        <p>
        <ol>
        <li>Reduzir a taxa de abandono escolar e melhorar os resultados escolares</li>
        <li>Reduzir os casos de indisciplina</li>
        <li>Promover a diversidade de atividades enquadradas nos conteúdos programáticos e / ou promovidas pela Escola</li>
        <li>Aumentar o envolvimento das famílias e da Comunidade Educativa na Escola</li>
        <li>Melhorar a organização curricular e pedagógica</li>
        <li>Promover a aferição da qualidade dos serviços</li>
        </ol>
        </p>
    </div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="1º" >1º Objetivo</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="2º" >2º Objetivo</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="3º" >3º Objetivo</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="4º" >4º Objetivo</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="5º" >5º Objetivo</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="obj[]" name="obj[]" value="6º" >6º Objetivo</label>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery ajax to send the form

```
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(e.target),
        fv    = $form.data('formValidation');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updates.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            var result = data.status;
            console.log(result);
            if(result === 'success'){
               alert("ok");
            }
            else{
                alert("erro");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have receive all data but not the values checked by user
In fiddler i can see all the data is passed but in my post php the values of checkbox is empty

This is my php

```
if ($novoPae != null) {
    $idutilizador = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userid');
    $cargo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cargo');
    $des = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'desc');
    $obj = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'obj');
    $periodo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'periodo');
    $previsto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'previsto');
    $data = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data');
    $orcamento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'orcamento');
    $destinatarios = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destinatarios');
    $obs = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'obs');
    echo $obj;
   /* $ret = $ebspma->novoPae($cargo, $idutilizador, $novoPae, $des, $obj, $periodo, $previsto, $data, $orcamento, $destinatarios, $obs);
    echo json_encode($ret);*/
}
```

From fiddler i have this in sintaxView

> cargo=171&novoPae=Atividade&desc=Descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o&**obj%5B%5D=2%C2%BA&obj%5B%5D=3%C2%BA&obj%5B%5D=4%C2%BA&**periodo=2%C2%BA+Periodo&previsto=Fevereiro&data=2015-12-14&orcamento=Or%C3%A7amento&destinatarios=Destinat%C3%A1rios&obs=Observa%C3%A7%C3%B5es&userid=1261

Comment: Is it necessary that they have same name?

Comment: `obj[]` is perfectly valid, it is presented as an array after submitting. For this to work it has to be provided identical to all corresponding elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). By default `filter_input()` doesn't handle arrays.

My testing form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="anne">
    <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="bob">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

First test result:

```
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo');
var_dump($foo);
// bool(false)
```

If you want to retrieve an array you have to specify the option [`FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php):

```
$foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
var_dump($foo);
// array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "anne" [1]=> string(3) "bob" }
```

Comment: Ok...i will try later and let you know.

Comment: No...it gives me Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given when when trying to insert into database

Comment: Since you haven't posted any of your database related code I can't answer this. It would be best to create a new question for this. If my answer solved the problem stated in this question you should accept it.